# QGIS graphical modeler and statistics tables

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, statistics

I have been able to use a processing tool available in QGIS, 'Statistics by Categories'to obtain some statistics for lengths of pipes of different materials within a polygon area. I am only actually interested in the sum of the lengths of pipes within each of the material categories.

I had therefore hoped to be able to either select the statistical measure of interest and ignore others within the tool while setting up the process, or I have tried to use the 'drop fields'algorithm on the result to generate a further result that only has my measure of interest included (but this only works on vector layers). Neither method does what I am hoping for.

Would anyone know of an appropriate processing tool or technique to achieve this?